# Ruby/Cucumber/Capybara Testing Multipart File Uploads

Tags: ruby, file-upload, cucumber, capybara, multipart

I'm using Cucumber/Capybara to test a web application.  I'm pretty much a complete beginner in Ruby and its a real testimony to the developers of Cucumber/Capybara just how far I have been able to test my application with only the miniscule amount of Ruby knowledge that I have.

However, as you've probably guessed, I've reach the point were I need some expert help.  I need to test a multipart file upload.  The problem is that the web application that I'm testing has a URL command interface, but no associated pages.  So I can't just load the page, fill in a parameter and push a button.  I have to format the POST command programatically.

Up until now, I have been interacting this the application exclusively using 'visit'.  i.e. i have steps definitions such as:

```
Given /^I delete an alert with alertID "([^"]*)" from the site$/ do |alertID|
visit WEB_SITE_ROOT + "/RemoteService?command=deleteAlert&siteName=#{$Site}&alertID=#{alertID}" 
end
```

But now I need to do some posts.   I found some code that seems to do what I need:

```
Given /^I upload the "([^"]*)" file "([^"]*)" for the alert$/ do |fileType, fileName|
file = File.new(fileName, "rb")
reply = RestClient.post(
  "#{WEB_SITE_ROOT}" + "/FileUploader?command=upload&siteName=#{$Site}&alertID=#{$OriginalAlertID}",
  :pict       =>  file,
  :function   =>  "#{fileType}",
  :content_type => 'multipart/jpg',
  )
end
```

But this is not running in the same cucumber/capybara session, and so is not authorised (one of the previous steps was a login).  Also, the reply from the web application is not picked up by cucumber/capybara and so my test for success/failure do not work.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

By default capybara uses the `Rack::Test` adapter which will bypass the HTTP server and interact with your Rack/your app directly. The POST request you're doing in your step won't go through capybara, hence why it's failing.

To upload files when using `Rack::Test` you'll need to use the Rails [#fixture_file_upload](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestProcess.html#method-i-fixture_file_upload) method, which by default should be available in your cucumber steps.